# How to ProGuard and Optimizer and Obfuscator in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, optimization, compiler-construction

I downloaded the eclipse from the **[google bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)** but yet I dont know if it is optimizing the code once it gets compiled. How do I enable optimiziation and obfuscation for my code in eclipse for java or do I need to get a special plugin to do so? I want to make my files as small as they can to be a quicker download for users
If this is a bad question please do not -rep me, just tell me and I'll remove it

Comment: javac itself optimizes the code a lot.

Comment: what that? Do I have to do something to eclipse to enable that? I really want to optimize my code for android developement

Comment: javac is the official Java compiler included in the JDK which Eclipse uses.

Comment: thanks, i didn't know that but does it also obfuscate the code, or is that already setup if I got the one that had the android sdk already installed

Comment: It does not obfuscate the code. add the -g:none option to compilation to make the file smaller.

Comment: An APK file is essentially a JAR. If someone wants, they can generate code from the APK. Why are you so set on having obfuscated code? There are other techniques to reduce application size. Such as not bundling any resources into the application and having them all downloaded when the application is loaded for the first time.

Comment: to make the file smaller for my android game... it would also make it harder for there to be cheaters to add mods and stuff. I did that to my javascript code and it shrinked. Also I wish there was a tutorial on how to do the -g and stuff. I use eclipse but I dont know how to enable those options

Comment: @JustinDanielson an apk file has a classes.dex which is a different format than jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used ProGuard once or twice, never extensively but my understanding is this: it is an external bundle of files that you must run (either command line or through its GUI) in order to use it. I have used the GUI and it gives you several different tabs for each of the options (Optimizing, Shrinking, and Obfuscation). You can find their project page [here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) with more information and detail on how to use it. As far as I know there is no IDE intergration for ProGuard.

Comment: I know there is an ant task for ProGuard.

Comment: Am sorry guys but i dont understand anything about the ant and command line version of the compiler. Sorry, I just press RUN in eclipse and it compiles the code and stuff. Thanks for the answers, I'll try to learn about ant and stuff then I'll do what you guys say

Comment: @nimsson Yes there is Automation, you can include it for Ant, Maven, etc. I've personally never used it but I know it exists.

Comment: Yeah, it is quite a bit more advanced than the average user. You need to mess with the build files in order to use the ant task, and that is not the best idea. You also have to make a Proguard file which tells it what to do.

Comment: I thought eclipse did all of that for me and that was why there are so many weird files when I create a new android project.... I though proguard and stuff was automatic without me doing anything....

Comment: @androidmaster As far as I know ProGuard is not run when you compile with eclipse, although I don't know the details of your Android Project setup so I couldn't say if you are working around that or not. My best guess would be to see if you have the GUI bundled with ProGuard and manually use it rather than rely on your IDE for it.